# как изменить значение переменной в js по нажатию кнопки на странице

Tags: javascript, bootstrap

есть Bootstrap кнопка вида:

```
<input type="submit" id="remove" class="btn btn-success" value="Поменять график">
```

есть переменная в JS вида:

```
let chart_type = 'line'
```

как мне изменить значение (chart_type = 'line') на (chart_type = 'bar') при нажатии на кнопку?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Раз уж у Вас есть ID кнопки под названием `"remove"`, то по нему Вы можете  создать событие `onclick`, позволяющее выполнить требуемые действия, примерно следующим образом:

```js
let chart_type = 'line';

document.getElementById("remove").onclick = function() {
  chart_type = 'bar';
  console.log("Значение переменной успешно изменено!");
};

document.getElementById("checkVar").onclick = function() {
  console.log("chart_type = " + chart_type);
};
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="remove" class="btn btn-success" value="Поменять график">
<button id="checkVar">Нажмите, чтобы узнать значение chart_type</button>
```

Comment: это работает, но только в консоли, сам график не меняется, походу нужно еще и чтоб старое значение пропадало

Comment: вот полная версия 

`let ctx = document.querySelector('#myChart').getContext('2d');
let chart_type = 'line' 
let myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: chart_type }`

'line' и 'bar' должны быть переключаемые по кнопке.
сможете помочь ?

Comment: есть [примеры](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36949343/chart-js-dynamic-changing-of-chart-type-line-to-bar-as-example), как правильно обновлять график